# Pushouts of commutative pseudomonoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, descent, 2-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a symmetric monoidal bicategory. Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has bicategorical coequalizers which are preserved by $\otimes$ in each variable. My question is if then the category of commutative [pseudomonoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudomonoid) $\mathrm{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ has bicategorical pushouts.

This is true for symmetric monoidal categories $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$. Here one constructs the pushout of monoid morphisms $(A,\mu_A,\eta_A) \leftarrow (C,\mu_C,\eta_C) \rightarrow (B,\mu_B,\eta_B)$ as the coequalizer $A \otimes_C B$ of the two evident morphisms $A \otimes C \otimes B \rightrightarrows A \otimes B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and endows it with a monoid structure. The most familiar case for this is $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Ab}$, which yields the construction of pushouts of commutative rings.

I don't see why this should not work for symmetric monoidal bicategories. But I was told that one has to use [codescent objects](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~slack/papers/codesc.html); I wonder why this is necessary. A reference for coproducts in $\mathrm{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ (which is the special case $C=\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}}$) is Theorem 5.2 in Schäppi's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3678) on ind-abelian categories.

Edit: I think I now understand why coequalizers are not enough. So assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has bicategorical codescent objects which are preserved by $\otimes$ in each variable (add additional assumptions if necessary). Does then $\mathrm{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ have bicategorical pushouts? It seems that Schäppi uses this (in the special case $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{cat}_{\mathrm{fc}/k}$, the category of essentially small finitely cocomplete $k$-linear categories) without proof [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6358) in Section 4.1. I assume that the codescent object is constructed in $\mathcal{C}$ (since we cannot just assume the existence of codescent objects in $\mathrm{CMon}(\mathcal{C}$), right?), but the proof that it has the structure of a commutative pseudomonoid, and that it is actually a codescent object in $\mathrm{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$, is missing.

I would already be happy for a detailed explanation or reference for the case $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{cat}$, i.e. how to construct bicategorical pushouts of small symmetric monoidal categories.

Comment: Have you tried to endow this coequalizer with a pseudomonoid structure and prove its universal property?  I expect that if you try to do that you'll see why you need codescent objects.

Comment: Thanks! I would be grateful for a more detailed explanation. @MikeShulman

Comment: In any case, what is true is that if a bicategoy has bicategorical coproducts and bicategorical coequalizers (by which I mean coisoinserters), then it has bicategorical pushouts - right? So the question here is how to construct coequalizers in $\mathrm{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: Well, you could also try writing it out explicitly in a case like $\mathcal C = \rm Cat$.  I expect you'll be able to define a multiplication on the coequalizer, but not to show that its associator satisfies the pentagon identity.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks! In fact I was able to define a symmetric monoidal structure on the coequalizer (lots of diagrams...), which made me believe that perhaps I *am* right after all, but it seems that the natural isomorphism (in the def' of a coequalizer) is not compatible with the symmetric monoidal structure. So perhaps one really needs codescent objects after all.

Comment: The intuitive reason why you shouldn't expect coequalizers to work is that when working with higher categories it almost never works to talk about isomorphisms that don't satisfy coherence conditions, and a bicategorical coequalizer is adding an isomorphism without a coherence condition.

Comment: It's a codescent object in CMon(C) because it's a reflexive codescent object, and reflexive codescent objects, like reflexive coequalizers and geometric realizations of simplicial objects, are automatically preserved in both variables together by any two-variable functor that preserves them in each variable separately.  Unfortunately I can't think of a reference at the moment.

Comment: BTW, for C=Cat there is another way to construct bicategorical colimits: the 2-category of symmetric monoidal categories is of the form T-Alg for a 2-monad T on Cat, so the technology of Blackwell-Kelly-Power "Two-dimensional monad theory" applies to show that it has all bicategorical colimits.  The approach there is to construct a suitable replaced colimit in the 2-category of symmetric monoidal categories and _strict_ functors and use the flexible replacement.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you! Your second comment confirms what I assumed is the proof outline: one takes the codescent object in $\mathcal{C}$ and then endows it with a structure of a pseudomonoid, using what you said about the compatibility of codescent objects and tensor products, right? Concerning the third comment: yes I was aware of that monad approach, but again here lots of details were unclear to me (and I didn't find any literature which explains in detail what I need), so I was hoping for a more direction construction.

Comment: @MikeShulman I have asked a separate question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349792/diagonal-of-a-diagram-of-codescent-objects

Comment: @MikeShulman Perhaps you can make your comments to an answer somehow, so that I can accept it? Meanwhile, I have found also an alternative proof which is an "expanded version" of my first (flawed) attempt and avoids codescent objects. :)

Comment: What does "expanded version" mean?  I'm pretty sure that the plain bicategorical coequalizer is actually wrong.  (I'll think about whether this discussion could be written as an answer.  It's tricky because the question kept changing.)

Comment: It's a bicategorical coequalizer followed by two bicategorical coequifiers.

Comment: @MikeShulman See here for the outline (I am writing up the details soon): http://prntscr.com/qmmw9f

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Probably essentially recapitulating the construction of codescent objects in terms of coequalizers and coequifiers, then.

Comment: @MikeShulman Yes I think so! But the proof that the tensor structure lifts is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize some of the comments:

I don't know a short answer for why a bicategorical coequalizer doesn't work.  If you try to give the bicategorical coequalizer the structure and universal property, you'll find that it just doesn't work somewhere.  The intuition is that in higher categories, when you have more coherence information, you generally have to use it rather than ignore it.

The fact that the codescent object is also a codescent object in commutative monoids follows from the fact that it is a reflexive codescent object, and that a two-variable functor preserving reflexive codescent objects in each variable separately also preserves them in both variables jointly.  This categorifies the corresponding fact for reflexive coequalizers in 1-categories, and decategorifies a corresponding statement for geometric realizations of simplicial objects in $\infty$-categories; your question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349792/49) was answered with a proof.

Finally, in $\rm Cat$ (or other locally presentable 2-categories) one can alternatively use the technology of Blackwell-Kelly-Power "Two-dimensional monad theory" to construct colimits in categories of (commutative) monoids, since they are of the form $T\rm Alg$ for an accessible 2-monad $T$.

Answer (score 0):

For a more elementary approach, see my preprint [Bicategorical colimits of tensor categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10123).