# Diagonal of a diagram of codescent objects

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits, 2-categories

Given the following diagram in a $2$-category, in which squares of the same  "type" commute, where each column and each row is a strong [codescent diagram](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001366) (**Edit**: it should be reflexive as well), is then the diagonal a codescent diagram as well?

[image]

Actually, for each row and each column we also have six $2$-isomorphisms (for example, $\xi^h_i : x^h_i d^h_i \to x^h_i c^h_i$ for the $i$th row), which I didn't write down here.

This question is motivated by Mike Shulman's comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275406/pushouts-of-commutative-pseudomonoids). In fact, this statement would probably be an important step to construct bicategorical pushouts of symmetric pseudomonoids.

I tried to find a proof, but basically get lost because of this huge amount of data.

Notice that this statement (if it is true) is a generalization of the corresponding $1$-dimensional statement about reflexive coequalizers (Sketches of an elephant, Lemma A.1.2.11). I would be very happy for a reference to the literature where this is proven. Instead of writing down a proof on my own, which will be probably too long anyway, I would like to cite and then use this result in a paper.

Comment: This follows from the fact (due to Steve Lack) that (reflexive) codescent objects are sifted flexible colimits (see Proposition 4 in John Bourke’s paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1203 for a proof). I can explain how when I get home.

Comment: I should also point out that for this result to hold, each row and column of your diagram must be a **reflexive** codescent diagram (see the paragraph before Proposition 4.3 of Lack's paper to which you link).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks very promising. I am looking forward to your answer. Actually Prop 4.3. in Lack's paper is then a special case of this statement (for the 2-category of small categories), and perhaps the proof can be generalized? Unfortunately Lack only sketches the proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment above, for this result to hold, each row and column of your diagram must be a **reflexive** codescent diagram. I do not know of any place in the literature where this result is explicitly stated, but, as I will explain below, it follows without difficulty from a result of Steve Lack.

(For simplicity, let me deal only with *strict* reflexive codescent objects. Since these are flexible colimits, one can deduce the fully weak bicategorical version of this result from the strict version by standard arguments.)

**Definition.** Let $\Delta_{\leq 2}$ denote the full subcategory of the simplex category $\Delta$ containing the objects $[0]$, $[1]$, and $[2]$, and let $W : \Delta_{\leq 2} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ denote the composite of the full inclusion $\Delta_{\leq 2} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ with the groupoid reflection functor $\mathbf{Cat} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$.  For any $2$-category $\mathcal{K}$, the **reflexive codescent object** of a functor $X : \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \longrightarrow \mathcal{K}$ is the colimit $W \ast X$ of $X$ weighted by $W$.

We will deduce the "diagonal lemma" of your question for reflexive codescent objects from the fact that reflexive codescent objects are **sifted colimits** (in the $\mathbf{Cat}$-enriched sense), i.e. that the functor $$W \ast (-) : [\Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op},\mathbf{Cat}] \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$$ preserves finite products. This fact is due to Steve Lack -- see Proposition 4.3 of

> Lack, Stephen. Codescent objects and coherence. *J. Pure Appl. Algebra* **175** (2002), no. 1-3, 223--241. [doi](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00136-6)

and Proposition 4 of

> Bourke, John. A colimit decomposition for homotopy algebras in Cat. *Appl. Categ. Structures* **22** (2014), no. 1, 13--28. [doi](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10485-012-9293-4)

Thanks to the "Fubini theorem" for iterated weighted colimits, we may state the diagonal lemma for reflexive codescent objects in the following form.

**Lemma** (diagonal lemma for reflexive codescent objects). Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a $2$-category and let $X \colon \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \times \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \longrightarrow \mathcal{K}$ be a functor. Then we have an isomorphism of weighted colimits in $\mathcal{K}$
$$W \ast (X \circ \delta) \cong (W \times W) \ast X,$$
either side existing if the other does. (Here $\delta$ denotes the diagonal functor $\Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \longrightarrow \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \times \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op}$).

**Remark.** It is also worth displaying the isomorphism of this lemma in coend form:
$$\int^{[k]} W^k \times X_{k,k} \cong \int^{[n],[m]} W^n \times W^m \times X_{n,m}.$$

**Proof of lemma.** The preservation of binary products of representables by the functor $W \ast (-) : [\Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op},\mathbf{Cat}] \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ implies, via the weighted colimit formula for left Kan extensions, that the functor $W \times W :  \Delta_{\leq 2} \times \Delta_{\leq 2} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ is the left Kan extension of $W \colon \Delta_{\leq 2} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ along the diagonal functor $\delta \colon \Delta_{\leq 2} \longrightarrow \Delta_{\leq 2} \times \Delta_{\leq 2}$. Hence the lemma follows from Theorem 4.38 of Kelly's *[Basic concepts of enriched category theory](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html)*. $\Box$

---

It is worth mentioning that, when working bicategorically (i.e. "up to equivalence"), the codescent object of a (pseudo)functor $X : \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \longrightarrow \mathcal{K}$ is simply its bicolimit. Hence the bicategorical version of the diagonal lemma for reflexive codescent objects -- which follows from the strict version by standard arguments -- is simply the statement that the diagonal functor $\Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \longrightarrow \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op} \times \Delta_{\leq 2}^\mathrm{op}$ is **2-final**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Can you perhaps say more about why strict reflexive codescent objects are sufficient? I don't know the "standard arguments" you are mentioning. And by the way, I am actually interested in bicategorical codescent objects, so your last paragraph is very helpful.

Comment: Essentially it’s a combination of the following facts. To prove the “weak” diagonal lemma in a general bicategory, it suffices to prove it for “weak” coreflexive descent objects (the dual bilimit notion) in **Cat**, since representable functors jointly detect bilimits. Next, any pseudofunctor from $\Delta_{\leq 2}$ to  **Cat** is equivalent to a strict one. Finally, the strict descent object of a functor from $\Delta_{\leq 2}$ to **Cat** is also its bilimit, since the weight $W$ defined above is a flexible (i.e. projective cofibrant) replacement of the terminal weight.

Comment: Your first sentence seems to suggest that the reflexivity hypothesis is not just sufficient but *required* — that without it, the result could fail. Did you intend to suggest this, and if so could you elaborate?

Comment: I did intend to suggest that. The diagonal lemma is very nearly equivalent to (reflexive) codescent objects being sifted colimits, so any example showing that non-reflexive codescent objects are not sifted (I don’t know any off the top of my head, but the literature asserts their existence) should also yield a counterexample to the diagonal lemma for non-reflexive codescent objects.

Comment: In Lack's paper, in the description of reflexive codescent data, a $2$-cell $ue \to ve$ is missing, right?

Comment: In your definition of the weight $W$, you use the groupoid reflection $\mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Cat}$. But this is not mentioned in Bourke's paper (also not in his thesis on codescent objects). Can you explain this difference? This must also be related to the category $\mathscr{D}_r$ in Lack's paper.

Comment: Bourke describes the same weight in the first sentence of Section 3.2 of his paper; he denotes it by $W_i$.

Comment: Certainly there should be an invertible $2$-cell $ue \to ve$, and I don't see at the moment that it can be built up from the other $2$-cells he lists.