# Relation between two limit presentations of Eilenberg--Moore objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, monads, 2-categories

Let $\mathbb{T}=({\cal T}\colon C\to C,\mu,\eta)$ be a monad (in the
$2$-category $\mathsf{Cat}$), which we view as a $2$-functor
$\mathbb{T}\colon\mathsf{B}\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}\to\mathsf{Cat}$ (where
$\mathsf{B}\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}$ is the classifying one-object
$2$-category for the monoidal category
$(\Delta_{\mathrm{a}},+,[-1])$). It is well-known that its
Eilenberg–Moore category $\mathbb{T}{-}\mathsf{Alg}$ is obtained as
the limit of
$\mathbb{T}\colon\mathsf{B}\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}\to\mathsf{Cat}$
weighted by the $2$-functor ${\cal
W}\colon\mathsf{B}\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}\to\mathsf{Cat}$
sending the object $\ast$ to ${\cal W}(\ast)=\Delta_{\mathrm{split}}$
(and with functoriality given by the restriction to
$\Delta_{\mathrm{split}}\subset\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}$ of the product).

It is perhaps less well-known, but was observed [in an answer by Peter
LeFanu Lumsdaine to another
question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/352917), that
$\mathbb{T}{-}\mathsf{Alg}$ can also be obtained by first taking the
inserter of the $1$-morphisms
${\cal T},\operatorname{id}_{C}\colon C\rightrightarrows C$ and then
taking two equifiers imposing the "associativity" and "unitality"
constraints, giving a version of the usual explicit description of EM
categories valid in any $2$-category. One recognises from this
particular combination of limits the construction of the lax descent
object of a lax co-coherence datum described (for the dual case of lax
codescent objects) above Proposition 2.1 in Lack's [**Codescent objects and
coherence**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00136-6),
and indeed one can then re-express $\mathbb{T}{-}\mathsf{Alg}$ as the
lax descent object of the diagram
$$
C
\substack{\xrightarrow{{\cal T}}\\ \xleftarrow{} \\
  \xrightarrow[\operatorname{id}_{C}]{}} C
\substack{\xrightarrow{{\cal T}}\\
  \xrightarrow{\vphantom{a}}\\
  \xrightarrow[\operatorname{id}_{C}]{\vphantom{a}}} C
$$
(where the unadorned arrows are also $\operatorname{id}_{C}$) with the
non-trivial $2$-arrows
$\mu\colon{\cal T}\circ{\cal T}\to\operatorname{id}_{C}\circ{\cal T}$
and
$\eta\colon\operatorname{id}_{C}\to\operatorname{id}_{C}\circ{\cal
  T}$.

Note that lax descent objects can also be described (Proposition 2.2
of *op. cit.*) as limits weighted by a somewhat inexplicit weight:
calling $\mathscr{D}_{\ell}^{\mathrm{op}}$, as in Lack's notation, the
$2$-category giving the shape for lax co-coherence data, the weight,
as an object of $\mathsf{Cat}^{\mathscr{D}_{\ell}^{\mathrm{op}}}$, is the
lax codescent object of the lax coherence datum provided by the dual
Yoneda embedding $(\mathscr{D}_{\ell}^{\mathrm{op}})^{\mathrm{op}}
\hookrightarrow\mathsf{Cat}^{\mathscr{D}_{\ell}^{\mathrm{op}}}$.

Now of course, since these two limit constructions describe the same
object, they must be equal, but I would like to know if there is a
more conceptual reason for this identification, *i.e.* a way of
deducing the second limit expression from the first. The latter
($\mathscr{D}_{\ell}^{\mathrm{op}}$-indexed) diagram seems to be a
kind of "unfolding" of the first
($\mathsf{B}\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}$-indexed) one, and so my question is
whether it is possible to make that relation precise and go from one
description to the other just by the calculus of weights.

A subsidiary question: In the first description, the $2$-functor
$\mathsf{B}\Delta_{\mathrm{a}}\to\mathsf{Cat}$ classifies a lax
$2$-functor $\ast\to\mathsf{Cat}$, and the Eilenberg–Moore category is
then its lax limit. Concomitantly, I have read [at the end of an
answer by Alexander Campbell](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349816) (but
do not know of a reference) that the descent object of a (non-lax)
co-coherence datum is simply its bilimit. Is it also true that the lax
descent object of a lax co-coherence datum is its (lax?)  bilimit, and
if so does this give a more direct answer (where one only has to
unfold the diagrams but not the conical weights) to my first question?